# SourceTree can't push to Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I try to push changes to Bitbucket but have exception

```
Pushing to https://wegorich@bitbucket.org/.../....git
2013-11-26 15:35:18.193 git-credential-sourcetree[19530:507] Error (internetKeychainItemForServer:withUsername:path:port:protocol:) - The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
fatal: Authentication failed
```

Repo path = https://wegorich@bitbucket.org/.../....git

Other Bitbucket project I can push and pull. :(

Comment: have you test your password? take a look at this explanation :https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/125892/submodule-with-different-user-fails-to-clone-push-with-sourcetree

Comment: Yep. The problem was: no repo write access :(